# mailboxer mark message as read

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mailboxer

Using the rails gem mailboxer

I have just started using it but I see that the SocialStream code base is quite heavy and doesnt provide a simple overview

I'd like to know how to properly work with notifications, so that if a message is sent, the receiver user clicks the message (in part of a conversation) so that it marks the message as read, this in turn will show the sender that the message is read by the receiver

Using the examples I cant seem to get it working. If I use

```
current_user.mailbox.inbox.unread_messages_count
```

I seem to get a static number that doenst change, even if I mark all my messages as read

Does anyone have a view on how to do this?

Also how do I empty all messages, conversations, receipts etc

Answer (score 1):

As per the Mailboxer readme, I saw this as the recommended way:

`current_user.mailbox.inbox({:read => false}).count`

I think that should update every time you refresh

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Take [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) tour to get to know how this site works and what it is for. Consider formatting your answer.

Comment: Would you like to provide me a link to the section of the readme?